# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'CMEngine': The specified module could not be found

Tags: dll, jna

So we integrate with a 3rd party DLL via JNA.  Occasionally they update their code which contains new parameters in functions etc as government mandates require.

Well I got their raw C/C++ code which they provide as their support to those companies that wish to run their software on UNIX machines.  Their code provided includes a makefile.  Normally we compile the code for UNIX and I end up with .so files and away I go happily on my way.  They usually supply a .dll equivalent for windows that we use for development and then our build-servers/live-servers use the .so one and everyone is happy.  However they decided to change up their project and use .Net and also change the parameters and order of them between their windows .net dll's and the c code's dlls.

So now I need to compile the C/C++ code for Windows and get a .dll in addition to compiling it for Linux and getting the .so file.  So I thought to myself -- sure no worries I can do that.  So I go into the makefile, find what I think would be the right thing to change.  I come with the following:

```
g++ -shared -lc -lstdc++ -o CMEngine.dll \
```

normally when compiling for linux we use something similar:

```
g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,libCMEngine.so.4.73 -o /lib/libCMEngine.so -lc -lstdc++ \
```

So in other words, both calls are almost identical.

Now for the part that's frustrating:  We have a JUnit test like good developers should that tests the integration of the various methods to make sure all is well.  Well in the test it gets to the following line:

```
public CMEngine INSTANCE = (CMEngine) Native.loadLibrary("CMEngine", CMEngine.class);
```

Also in our unit test on startup we have the following param:

```
-Djna.library.path=C:\java\api\dll\
```

So then I run the test.  If I have the old .dll in the java/api/dll/oldDll.dll folder there when the test runs I get the following error:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000180016dc0, pid=15132, tid=14804
...
```

However if I place my new .dll in there with the same name java/api/dll/newDll.dll then I get the error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'CMEngine': The specified module could not be found.
```

It appears then that old dll while it doesn't work because of the new param changes it at least finds the dll and loads it up hence the seg-fault error.  However that also means then that it should find my new dll that I put in the exact same spot (overwriting the old one with the exact same name) and then I get the module could not be found.

So my questions are the following:
 1. Does the fact that it cannot find the module mean that I'm creating a bad .dll -- something with the name of the dll but no real semblence of a dll because my build command is wrong?
 2. Does the name mean anything in a dll?  If I name my dll bobbysDll.dll does that have any impact on anything?
 3. When compiling for Windows does the process differ entirely from a Unix system?  In other words was my assumption that I remove the .so bit basically from the same compile command and then voila I get a workable .dll for windows.  Perhaps I should mention that I'm using cygwin to run the make command.  I downloaded visual studio if there's a better way to generate a dll out of it.  I'm willing to try anything.

I appreciate any and all insight on this.  I pretty much spent my whole day trying to better understand what I might be doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

1. Does the fact that it cannot find the module mean that I'm creating a bad .dll -- something with the name of the dll but no real semblence of a dll because my build command is wrong?

There several reasons that causes "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError". For example

- windows can not find the dll
- trying to use x64 jvm to load x86 dll or use x86 jvm to load x64 dll
- the dll missing other depended dlls(you can try [dependency worker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/))
- the dll is broken

I suggest that, you'd better write a exe program that use that dll, to make sure the dll can be loaded rightly.

2. Does the name mean anything in a dll?

do you mean the dll name? in your case I do not think this matters, because jni use Loadlibrary to load the dll. but if your exe is linked to a dll's import library, it matters.

If I name my dll bobbysDll.dll does that have any impact on anything?

In your JNI code, you should use:

```
System.loadLibrary("bobbysDll");
```

3. When compiling for Windows does the process differ entirely from a Unix system? In other words was my assumption that I remove the .so bit basically from the same compile command and then voila I get a workable .dll for windows. Perhaps I should mention that I'm using cygwin to run the make command.

I suggest that, use VisualStudio to build your dll. And you need a def file to tell VC which functions to export.